# Navigation: Displaying the textview text in other controller

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, uibutton, uitextview

I have a main view controller(embedded in navigation controller) which has a label on which a button I have placed. When I click on the button, it will go to the next view controller which contains a text view and two buttons. Two buttons are cancel and Post. Cancel button will just have to take me to the main view controller. Post should take me to the main view controller with the text what I have written in the text view. But when I press either button It is crashing. 
For cancel button I have written the code :

```
    - (IBAction)cancelButton:(id)sender {
    NewRequestViewController *back=[[UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil]
                                    instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"NewRequestViewController"];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:back animated:NO];

}
```

and for Push button I have written the code like below:

```
  - (IBAction)postComment:(id)sender {

    _parent.commentBox.text=_textView.text;
    [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];

}
```

where commentBox is the outlet of the label which is below the button.

Crash report says that:
Finishing up a navigation transition in an unexpected state. Navigation Bar subview tree might get corrupted.

Please anyone help me out with this. 
Thank you for any help.

Answer (score 0):

Use this for cancel Button event.

```
-(IBAction)cancelPressed:(id)sender
{
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

For posting the text data to your destination View Controller, you can use the `prepareForSegue` method like this.

```
-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    DestinationViewController *destController = [segue destinationViewController];
    destController._yourTextView.text == _yourText.text;
    }
}
```

Here, yourTextView is the TextView property that is to be declared on the DestinationViewController and import its .h file in your source Controller and assign as the current text value to it as shown above.

Since you are using button IBAction for posting data, you need to use `performSegueWithIdentifier` method in your button IBAction. Something like this :

```
- (IBAction)postComment:(id)sender {
[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"yourSegueIdentifier" sender:nil];
}
```

This will automatically call `prepareForSegue` which will show up your destination View Controller.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you for the help. But even when I changed , app is crashing for the same reason. It says that"Finishing up a navigation transition in an unexpected state. Navigation Bar subview tree might get corrupted." What I need to change then?

Comment: So whether you press cancel or Post button, they both lead to the same Controller, right ? Also, that controller is your parent controller and the current controller is your child controller.

Comment: yeah.. They both lead to the same controller. cancel with no text and Post with the text of text view. as you said current controller is the child controller.

Answer (score 0):

Try using following code for cancel action :

```
[self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

And for post action I recommend you to use Unwind Segues

http://www.absoluteripple.com/1/post/2013/08/using-ios-storyboard-segues.html

Comment: Thanks for the reply. When I used the above code for cancel button its again crashing 
Crash report :"Finishing up a navigation transition in an unexpected state. Navigation Bar subview tree might get corrupted."
Thread!:EXC_BAD_ACCESS(code=2....)

Answer (score 0):

How u navigate from main view controller to next view controller. if using storyboard segue mean check this:

I Think you using push segue  for navigate from mainviewcontroller to next view controller.
 use modal segue to navigate i think it work for u.

Answer (score 0):

**For Cancel button ->**

You can use [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];

and

**For Post button  ->**

You want to pass some text to parent view controller, So you can have a delegate method of child view controller which parent will implement and you can pass the text from child to parent from that delegate method right before popViewControllerAnimated.